# How do i create an instance dynamically from a class using a method in Java

Tags: java

Hi I am a Newbie in Java , 
I want to create an instance `student[0]`, `student[1]`, `student[2]`, from the object `Class student` by invoking a method call `createStudentInstance ()`

Can anyone help to shed some light

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried something ? Could you be more specific about which part of this is a problem ? Maybe give your current implementation code

Comment: Have you tried using a constructor ?

Comment: Any Java book will be great source of light in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constructor

```
public class Student
{
  public Student()
  {
     // Initialize attributes
  }
}
```

And call `new Student()` in your method to get an instance.

```
public void createStudentInstance()
{
  Student myStudent = new Student();
  // Do some stuff
  return myStudent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create instance of object by invoking its constructor.
If you want to create an instance of dynamically loaded class, you do it this way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("Foo").newInstance();

            //or if you want to invoke constructor which takes some arguments:

            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Foo");
            Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(int.class);
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            constructor.newInstance(7);
            constructor.setAccessible(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("Hello foo!");
    }

    public Foo(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hello foo with number " + i + "!");
    }
}
```